# Adding environment variable from command prompt / batch file

Tags: registry, environment-variables, batch-file, regedit

I am trying to add a environment variable (System) in my batch file.
The below command says ERROR: Invalid syntax. Can some one help.
For me it looks good.

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment /v ToDelete /t REG_SZ /d "192.168.00.00"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to quote the registry key as it has spaces

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v ToDelete /t REG_SZ /d "192.168.00.00"
```

Answer (score 2):

SetX.exe is probably the easiest way to do this in a batch file.  It also feels a bit safer than directly writing to the Registry just to add an Environment Variable.

[SetX syntax page](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

For your example the variable's:

- Space = System
- Name  = ToDelete
- Value = 192.168.00.00

The SetX command line would be:

```
SetX.exe ToDelete "192.168.00.00" /m
```

Note that this CMD was executed as an administrator.  Depending on your systems setup SetX may not run under your users permissions.

[image: SetX command line in CMD]

Another thing to remember about SetX is that the update does not happen to the Environment in the current CMD window.  you have to either also run a Set for the variable (temporary) or close and reopen CMD to see the update.

In most cases (in scripts) it means running both commands. Note below this is a standard CMD session (has been closed and reopened).

[image: Showing the Set in CMD]

Comment: No, it comes in all the newer Windows OSes.  However in older versions it may need to be downloaded from MS.  Example: for Windows XP you can get it in the Windows [XP SP2 support tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546).

Comment: is this possible to define a System variable with SetX command?

Comment: @ir-tech, yes the /M switch.  Open a command prompt and do a SET /? for the full syntax details.